# what is the difference between gene and allele?

Tags: chromosome

I want to know about gene and allele As we know allele is pair of genes they are ;present on only one chromosome or on homologous chromosomes? Or its like that;one chromosome has only one gene out of an allele and other homologous chromosome has another gene from the same allele?please clear this

Answer (score 1):

An allele is a variant form of a gene.

You can obtain a more detailed explanation of alleles using [Encyclopaedia Brittanica](https://www.britannica.com/story/whats-the-difference-between-a-gene-and-an-allele).